# Where pyinstaller path must be

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I'm on Windows and my python path is `C:\Python27`.
when I unpacked the archive I found the file `pyinstaller-2.0` 
Where that file path must be ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyInstaller can run as a stand-alone application, so it need not be placed inside the `C:\Python27` directory.  You could put it in `C:\Program Files` for example, and then invoke the PyInstaller application like this from a `cmd.exe` shell:

```
c:\python27\python.exe "c:\Program Files\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller.py" --help
```